# Getting data from related table in Codeigniter -- translating MySQL query into CI MVC

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have worked with examples from a few different StackOverflow posts to get data from related tables in CI, but haven't been successful in connecting my tables in the "where" part, and I'd like to understand how to translate that from a MySQL query to the CI MVC.

This is the MySQL query that works to get the dctag fields from the dctags table where the dctag_id in the articles table matches:

```
$dctagger = $article['dctag_id'];
$query = "SELECT `dctitle`, `dctag_id` FROM dctags WHERE dctag_id = '$dctagger'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
```

This is the code for the Model, Controller, and View files:

Model -

```
public function get_article_dctag() {
$this->db->select('*')
->from('dctags')
->where('dctag_id', $this->$data['dctag_id']);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array(); }
```

Controller -

```
public function article($slug) {
$data['article'] = $this->article_model->get_article($slug);
$data['dctag'] = $this->article_model->get_article_dctag();
$this->load->view('templates/header-article', $data);
$this->load->view('article', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer-home'); }
```

View -

```
<?php foreach ($dctag as $dctag_item): ?>
<title><?php $dctag_item['dctitle']; ?></title>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Error -
"A PHP Error was encountered... Severity: Notice... Message: Undefined variable: data...Filename: models/article_model.php" (see Model code above)

The problem is the variable $this->... and I don't know what that needs to be. Thanks for explanations/clarification -- in advance!

Comment: `$this->$data['dctag_id']` from where you getting this in model

Comment: From the controller ($data['dctag')? That's my problem -- I don't understand how the model retrieves the current page's dctag_id -- which belongs to the article page that is being displayed, so that it can match that dctag_id of that particular article to the dctag_id in the dctags table.

Comment: you can't use `$this->$data['dctag_id']` inside model you have to send some parameters to avail in model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `dctag_id` is in `$data['article']` then use following code

**On Controller**

```
public function article($slug) 
{
    $data['article'] = $this->article_model->get_article($slug);
    $data['dctag'] = $this->article_model->get_article_dctag($data['article']['dctag_id']);
    $this->load->view('templates/header-article', $data);
    $this->load->view('article', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer-home'); 
}
```

**On your Model**

```
public function get_article_dctag($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('dctags')
             ->where('dctag_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

Comment: Mystery solved! You just made this problem very understandable. I thank you very much, Vinie!

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you should pass the variable on the get_article_dctag($var) 
This will be the reference on your model get_article_dctag() and this should have a parameter of what you are searching for. In your structure it seems that Model cant locate your $data['dctag_id'] in your function

In the controller

```
$dctag_id = 2
$this->article_model->get_article_dctag($dctag_id);
```

In your model

```
function get_article_dctag($dctag_id){
$this->db->where('dctag_id',$dctag_id);}
```

Hopes it will help you a lot

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the code to match this and get no errors, but get no data in the view.

Comment: Update: when I add <?php print_r($dctag); ?> it outputs an array of all the correct data, but it just won't output in the title tag of the view, so something is wrong with my view, but this does work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you very much, Jonas. You got me on the way to the right answer and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome ... Happy coding jamie :)